# What do I need to apply an RMAN backup from one server to another

Tags: oracle11g, database-backups, rman

Right now I have been givin a controlfile some backupfiles and an spfile.ora

How do I apply these to a database on a server that is not the one they were created from.

If further info is needed please let me know. I am eager to get this process laid out for the next time I have to accomplish it.

I have tried to look up the process but keep seeing things about catalogs and such that I don't feel apply to this situation.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

I believe I have thr right files  but this is where im currently stuck -

```
RMAN> recover database;

Starting recover at 25-JUL-13
allocated channel: ORA_DISK_1
channel ORA_DISK_1: SID=770 device type=DISK

starting media recovery

unable to find archived log
archived log thread=1 sequence=6173
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03002: failure of recover command at 07/25/2013 20:49:59
RMAN-06054: media recovery requesting unknown archived log for thread 1 with sequence 6173 and starting SCN of 10866915410156
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my question ended up being to run recover database with the noredo option. Then to open the database use alter database open resetlogs;

```
recover database noredo;
```

Hope this might help anyone who runs into the same issues and sorry I couldn't lay out a better explanation.